# Facebook friend-selector dialog in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

is there a way to have my iphone native app display the friend-selector dialog of facebook? Or do i have to manually retrieve the user's friends and create the dialogs myself?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to do the same thing. Did you have to build it yourself ?

Comment: Finally we didn't use facebook at all... But at the time it looked like there wouldn't be another way other than building it myself... Didn't check lately to see if there has been any updates.

Answer (score 0):

In the most current SDK you are able to do this with the friend picker.

```
// Initialize the friend picker
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = 
    [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
// Set the friend picker title
friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";

// TODO: Set up the delegate to handle picker callbacks, ex: Done/Cancel button

// Load the friend data
[friendPickerController loadData];
// Show the picker modally
[friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES handler:nil];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/friendpicker-ui-control/